# spanning text border overlapping itself

Tags: html, css

On my website in the admin section i have  the ability to edit previously posted blogs. It works fine But its a little ugly and i can't find adequate css to fix the situation.

http://jsfiddle.net/z7cgu97q/1/

basically each blog posting looks like this:

```
<div> 
    <span class="edit" contenteditable="true">
        this is an editable title"
    </span>
</div> 

<div> 
    <span class="edit" contenteditable="true"> 
        This paragraph contains a blog post which is editable by the user. It looks a little strange. and it looks even worse if there is a line-wrap
    </span>
</div>
```

and the css is

```
.edit{
    background-color:#FFD685;
    border:1px solid #998050;
    padding:3px;
}
```

the spans overlap eachother and it looks really odd. If i take off the `padding:3px;` it looks better, but the text-wrap for the long post still looks terrible. ultimately, i would like it to be the size of the line, if there is wrap the height of the box would encompass that  without a border between them.

Comment: It looks better to me if I add display:inline-block to the .edit class. However I'm not sure if the result is what you are looking for - what do you think?

Comment: Why does the span need a border? What's the desired effect that you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/z7cgu97q/3/

Just add following code to your `CSS`:

```
display:block;
```

`<span>` is `display:inline` by default, so the borders and padding you added aren't actually affecting it's size. You're seeing the overlap because the width of the border/padding is larger than the line-height

Comment: also you can add float: left to the span elements to keep the first span element width